# Why the need for $1/2\le r <1$ in Eudoxus's method of exhaustion?

Tags: limits, proof-explanation, math-history

I'm reading Merzbach and Boyer's *A History of Mathematics* and finished the section on Hellenic traditions wherein the method of exhaustion is introduced. The section from the text reads,

> If from any magnitude there be subtracted a part **not less than its half** (emphasis mine), and if from the remainder one again subtracts not less than its half, and if this process of subtraction is continued, ultimately there will remain a magnitude less than any preassigned magnitude of the same kind.

In modern notation: if $M$ is a given magnitude, $\varepsilon$ a preassigned magnitude of the same kind, and $r$ is a ratio such that **$\frac{1}{2}\le r < 1$**, then there is a positive integer $N$ for which $M(1-r)^N < \varepsilon$.

An application of this is immediately given by showing the ratio of areas of circles is equal to the squares of the diameters (the proposition being used to dispense with the $<$ and $>$ cases).

My question is: why the need for the condition $\frac{1}{2}\le r <1$? Even without modern notation, clearly for $\frac{1}{2}\le r <1$, $(1-r)\le \frac{1}{2}$; then by bisections it is easy to show there is some $N_0$ for which $M (1/2)^{N_0}<\varepsilon$. In fact, for $0\le c<1$, it seems easy to give a proof that there is some ${N_1}$ such that $c^{N_1}<\frac{1}{2}$, and then taking $N_2=N\cdot N_1$, the result is the same as before. But again, I don't understand the necessity of restricting to half-magnitudes.

This isn't meant to denigrate the ancients; rather, I'm wondering if it comes from a geometric or cultural stipulation that isn't explicitly mentioned. For instance, in the next chapter on Euclid, the equation $ax-x^2=b^2$ is considered, with the proviso that $a>2b$; this is to ensure the quadratic has two real solutions, as the Greeks would have expected. I'm wondering if there is a factor, besides maybe convenience, that led to this proviso.

Comment: I imagine that they found this intuitively obvious enough to take for granted if $r\geq 1/2$ but maybe not for smaller $r$.  Indeed, it is far from obvious that it should be true if $r$ is very small.

Comment: @EricWofsey that's fair. The 'modern' way would probably use the Monotone Convergence Theorem, but I'm not sure if that would have been known. If one buys that eventually $(c^{-1})^N > 1 + N c^{-1}$, then the result is equivalent to $1/(1+N c^{-1})<\varepsilon$, which is basically the Archimedean property.

Comment: Another idea I had that might have been contemporary is: suppose not; then $(1-r)^N\ge \varepsilon$. The case $(1-r)\le \frac{1}{2}$ is obvious by bisection. But then in fact one must have $(1-r)\ge 1/\sqrt{2}$, else taking $2N$ for $N$ gives a ratio less than $1/2$. Similarly, we must have $1-r \ge 2^{-1/4}$, and this can be repeated. But by squeezing we eventually contradict $1-r<1$.